# How do i get gitlab to use my private trust certificate generated by an internal CA

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, gitlab, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-helm

I am attempting to install gitlab using helm. I have a certificate issued to me by the internal Certificate Authority and I have used the `.pem` and `.key` file to generate a tls secrete with this command:

```
kubectl create secret tls gitlab-cert --cert=<cert>.pem --key=<cert>.key
```

When I run the helm installation, I am expecting to be able to view gitlab with `https://{internal-domain}`, however I get the below image.

[image]

**HELM installtion configuration**

```
helm install gitlab gitlab/gitlab \
  --timeout 600s \
  --set global.hosts.domain=${hosts_domain} \
  --namespace ${helm_namespace} \
  --set global.hosts.externalIP=${static_ip} \
  --set postgresql.install=false \
  --set global.psql.host=${postgres_sql_ip} \
  --set global.psql.password.secret=${k8s_password_secret} \
  --set global.psql.username=${postgres_sql_user} \
  --set global.psql.password.key=${k8s_password_key}
  --set global.psql.ssl.secret=${psql_ssl_secret} \
  --set global.psql.ssl.clientCertificate=${psql_ssl_client_certificate} \
  --set global.psql.ssl.clientKey=${psql_ssl_client_key} \
  --set global.psql.ssl.serverCA=${psql_ssl_server_ca} \
  --set global.extraEnv.PGSSLCERT=${extra_env_pg_ssl_cert} \
  --set global.extraEnv.PGSSLKEY=${extra_env_pg_ssl_key} \
  --set global.extraEnv.PGSSLROOTCERT=${extra_env_pg_ssl_root_cert} \
  --set global.host.https=true \
  --set global.ingress.tls.enabled=true \
  --set global.ingress.tls.secretName=${gitlab-cert} \
  --set certmanager.install=false \
  --set global.ingress.configureCertmanager=false \
  --set gitlab.webservice.ingress.tls.secretName=${gitlab-cert}
```

The pods run fine.

Comment: The error you have there is `CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM`. It seems you should probably regenerate your certificate using a stronger algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Posted community wiki answer for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

Based on @sytech comment:

> The error you have there is `CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM`. It seems you should probably regenerate your certificate using a stronger algorithm.

You are probably using some weak signature algorithm. Both [Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/education/tls#TOC-Deprecated-and-Removed-Features) and [Mozilla Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Weak_Signature_Algorithm)  are not [treating certificates based on weak algorithms as secure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Weak_Signature_Algorithm):

> SHA-1 certificates will no longer be treated as secure by major browser manufacturers beginning in 2017.

> Support for MD5 based signatures was removed in early 2012.

Please make sure that you are [using more secure algorithm](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/):

> We encourage Certification Authorities (CAs) and Web site administrators to upgrade their certificates to use signature algorithms with hash functions that are stronger than SHA-1, such as SHA-256, SHA-384, or SHA-512.

Another option is that it may be issue at your end - check your network and browser settings - [steps are presented in this article](https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/fix-neterr-cert-weak-signature-algorithm-error/).